# Ruby on Rails giving me errors...

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So i've been following DevTips ruby on rails blog tutorial on YouTube but i keep getting errors:

```
app/views/posts/new.html.erb:11: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end
app/views/posts/new.html.erb:13: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting ')'
app/views/posts/new.html.erb:15: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
```

Now... For one my code isnt even 15 lines long... which is one reason why im so lost. Here is my code:

```
<h1>New Post</h1>

<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :title %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :title %><br />
  <br />
  <%= f.label :body %><br />
  <%= f.text_area :body %><br />
  <br />
  <%= f.submit %>
<%= end %>
```

Any help with this. I'm completely baffled...

Answer (score 6):

> syntax error, unexpected keyword_end

You need to change `<%= end %>` to `<% end %>`